# What is the allowed $k$ values in nearly free electron model?

Tags: solid-state-physics, physical-chemistry, crystals, electronic-band-theory

One explanation on bandgap formation uses nearly free electron theory and Bragg reflection. The diagram used for the explanation appears:

[image]

taken from [here](https://slidetodoc.com/7-energy-bands-bloch-functions-nearly-free-electron/).

I also learnt that in free electron theory, not all k are allowed. For a cubic lattice with side length a,

$$k= \pm\sqrt{k_x^2+k_y^2+k_z^2}, {\space} k_x=\frac{n_x\pi}{a}, {\space} k_y=\frac{n_y\pi}{a},{\space} k_z=\frac{n_z\pi}{a}$$

$$k = \pm \frac{n\pi}{a}, {\space} n=\sqrt{n_x^2+n_y^2+n_z^2}$$

where $n_x, n_y, n_z$ all must be integers.

That is, not all k are allowed. However, those k allowed ($\frac{\pm \pi}{a}, \frac{\pm 2\pi}{a}$...) will always satisfy Bragg condition.

Doesn't that mean that all states will then satisfy Bragg condition and no band will form? To put my question simply,

[image]

why is there allowed energy/ k in the red-circled regions when those k are not allowed from the solution of SE with periodic boundary conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing the size of the entire crystal with the size of a single unit cell.  Furthermore, you have used reflecting boundary conditions which require $n_x, n_y, n_z$ to be positive integers, but in the diagram $k$ can be negative so we need periodic boundary conditions which include negative integers.

The diagram considers a one-dimensional crystal for simplicity, which I'll assume to be in the $x$ direction. In such a crystal, if the unit cell has length $a$ and there are $N$ of them, the crystal has length $L=Na$. This $L$ is what should be used to find the allowed $k_x$.  Periodic boundary conditions require that the plane wave $\psi(x)=e^{ik_x x}$ is equal on either side of the crystal, so $\psi(0)=\psi(L)$ giving

$$1=e^{ik_x L}\Rightarrow k_x=\frac{2\pi n}{L}=\frac{2\pi n}{Na}$$

where $n$ is *any* integer, not just a positive integer. Note that what I call $k_x$ is what the diagram calls $k$, which is quite confusing because $k$ can also mean the magnitude of the wavevector (which would be positive).

As $N>1$ there are values of $k_x$ which lie inside the first Brillouin zone (i.e. have $-\pi/a<k_x<\pi/a$) and do not satisfy the Bragg condition. In fact, usually $N\gg 1$ as there are a macroscopic number of atoms in a crystal, so the spacing between allowed $k_x$ states is much smaller than the size of the Brillouin zone, and  we can consider there to be a continuum of $k_x$ states as is shown on the diagram.

Comment: The periodic boundary condition, $\psi(0) = \psi(L)$, the L is the length of the bulk crystal, not of the unit cell? What is the rationale for that? I thought it should be that of unit cell because same values of wavefunction repeat at same position in different unit cells.

Comment: I can follow your argument, just couldn't get the meaning of L in the boundary condition. I read $\psi(x) = \psi(x+L)$, if L = length of the bulk crystal, x + L already outside of the crystal, then what will be the interpretation on the equation?

Comment: You can think of it like this: instead of a one-dimensional crystal with actual ends, you join the ends together and make it into a circle. The physics must repeat itself when you move around the circle so $\psi(0) = \psi(L)$. What you call $x=0$ is arbitrary so this is the same as $\psi(x) = \psi(x+L)$.

Comment: You might then ask how can we consider it to be a circle even when it is not. The answer is that most physical quantities are measured far from the boundary and so are independent of the choice of boundary conditions.